# Sequelize - How to get sources id array on target belongsToMany association

Tags: javascript, mysql, associations, sequelize.js, has-and-belongs-to-many

Say I have a `Student` model and a `Class` model, and

`Student.belongsToMany(Class, through: {StudentClasses})`.

In the DB, `StudenClasses` table has `id`, `student_id`, `class_id`, and id like to have all the associated `student_id`s of a `Class` instance by that table

How can I have on my `Class` model an array containing all of the associated `Student` IDs?

I've been struggling for a few days now, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I only found a work around solution. Get *Class* by *id*. Do not forget to include all attributes. So we will have an array of Student here. And then get all ids

Comment: Ahhh Why dont you query on **StudentClass** model?

Comment: @ToanTran Thanks for your replies! :) What I'm trying to achieve is having this array on an instance, without having to query other models for that information.. unfortunately i ended up using the `getClasses().map(class => class.classId)` ... :\